# how to change email:- owner@example.com in home page in my localhost.?

Tags: magento-1.9, email-templates, backend, header

how to change this in email address in file header_left_links.php .:-

```
<?php
    $general_email = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/email');
?>

<ul class="list-inline">
<li>
<a href="mailto:<?php echo $general_email;?>"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i> <?php echo $general_email;?></a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change this email from the admin panel, go to:

**System -> Configuration -> Store Email Address** (this is in the left side menu)

[image]

There you will see different email addresses, change the ones you need.

Check this post for more details: http://www.hostknox.com/tutorials/magento/store-emails